# How to prevent from Firebase Attack Database ? (More than 100 anonymous account created in one day)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have never made any promotion,ads,... for my app. 
On my Google Play Developper account, I got 31 active installations. 
During the last 5 days, I got more than 150 anonymous accounts created (100 on 7 October). I suspect someone creating lots of account.
I put an event ("account_created") each time an account is created. This event was triggered only 40 times.
All the activity seems to be from Puerto Rico.
Some of these account appear only in tab "Authentification" but not in my database.

How can I prevent from this to happend next time?

And How can I bulk delete these fake accounts from "Authentification" **and** from my database (These are define by their FirebaseId as primary key).

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can't prevent such accounts from being created. To clean them up in bulk, you can use the Firebase Admin SDK (for both [Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin) and [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start)).

How to precisely delete the users is mostly a matter of how you determined what users are incorrect. Firebase has no way to determine that for you, as it could just as easily be that your code is (intentionally or not) creating multiple accounts.